# How to fetch the GET/POST elements in a form without knowing the name of the controls inside the form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I had the list of items. When the user clicks a item, a div is generated with a textbox:

`<input type="text" name="(DYNAMICALLY ASSIGNED VALUE)" />`

So user can select multiple items. For each item a textbox is generated dynamically inside the form. When the user clicks the submit button, I want to fetch the GET/POSTED elements. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a for-each loop:

```
foreach ($_GET as $get_key => $get_value)
```

Comment: Can we use it for POST also??

Comment: Yes, they're both just arrays.

Comment: While you're here, it also works for `$_COOKIE`, `$_FILE` and all the other superglobal arrays. Or rather, all other arrays.

Comment: It might be worth adding that it would be wise to ensure that sound security measures are in place, especially when you actually have no idea what the data is you're accepting. If it's dynamic, treat it like nuclear waste.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `foreach` loop on `$_POST` like Matthew suggested or you could set the names of the inputs as an array

for example

```
<input type="text" name="foo[]">

foreach ($_POST['foo'] as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```

The data would look like something like this

```
[foo] => Array
     (
         [0] => ...
         [1] => ...
         [2] => ...
         [3] => ...
     )
```