# Is there a way to find out POST variables without knowing their names?

Tags: php, html

I have a form that gets its names for checkboxes dynamically. Is there a way to find out the names of the unknown variables? For example:

```
 foreach($value as $option){
            $html .= "<input type='checkbox' name='".$key."[]' value='$option'>".htmlspecialchars($option)."</input>";
    }
```

I need to know what the `_POST['']` would be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch the GET/POST elements in a form without knowing the name of the controls inside the form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455437/how-to-fetch-the-get-post-elements-in-a-form-without-knowing-the-name-of-the-con)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the predefined variable [$_POST](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp) and loop over :

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    // $key will be the name
    // $value will be the value of $_POST[$key]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can loop over the post and get fields dynamically:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

You can do the same with $_GET.

Answer (score 3):

You can name your checkboxes 'checkbox[$key][]' and iterate over $_POST[$key] using foreach

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the `$_POST` variable just like any other array

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    echo "$key is $value";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a function - `get_defined_vars()` - that returns an array with all defined variables. Try the code below

```
$arr = get_defined_vars();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr);
```