# Submitting values with $_POST in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form with fields that are generated dynamically via a loop.
It's a pair of fields: name/email. Loop generates two input fields for each value. There's always an email, while name sometimes can be blank.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name['.$i.']" value="'.$output['0'].'">
    <input type="text" name="email['.$i.']" value="'.$output['1'].'"> 
</div>
```

I understand that $_POST will generate an array, something like this:

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [1] => Fname Lname [2] => ) [email] => Array ( [1] => abc@email.com [2] => abc@gmail.com ) )
```

Once I submit this form how do I get the values into my db table? Having difficulty visualizing this loop with two fields...

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477632/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-post-variables-without-knowing-thier-names

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know how to get the values that are posted, and generate an SQL query to add them to your database - is that right? If so what have you tried?

Comment: To make sure `$_POST` has the contents you expect add a this statement to your page `print_r($_POST);` then you will be able to see what's in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Having difficulty visualizing this loop with two fields

You have to choose one of the fields as a reference for the loop:

```
$names = $_POST['name'];
foreach($names as $key=>$name) {
    // $name is already defined. Define further fields based on $key
    $email = $_POST['email'][$key];
    // DB logic goes here. Do not forget to sanitize your inputs!
}
```

Comment: That's it. I will use email since it is never empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    ...
}
?>
```